# Como permitir espaço em branco em qualquer parte da sequência numa expressão regular?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho um campo que aceita no mínimo 12 caracteres alfanumérico, sendo entre eles 9 caracteres numéricos. Mas tem um porém, que aceite espaço em branco seja lá qual for a posição.

```
function validaCampo(sCampo) {
        var filter = /^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=(?:.*?\d){9})[a-z\d]{12,}$/i;
        if (filter.test(sCampo)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Acho que colocando o `\ ` ao final dentro do `[]` deve funcionar. `var filter = /^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=(?:.*?\d){9})[a-z\d\ ]{12,}$/i;`

Comment: Uma dica de melhoria: `^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=(?:\D*\d){9})[a-z\d ]{12,}$` - usar principalmente `\D*` (zero ou mais caracteres não numéricos) é mais eficiente que `.*?`, já que `.*?` gera mais possibilidades a serem testadas e quando a string é inválida a regex demora mais pra perceber isso. Compare, [essa](https://regex101.com/r/Se0jlf/1/debugger) leva quase 2000 passos até falhar, já [essa](https://regex101.com/r/6Muqob/1/debugger) leva só 52 passos. Pra strings pequenas não faz muita diferença, mas se tiver muitos testes e strings grandes, pode ser que ajude...

Comment: @hkotsubo Entendido. Farei. Obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta colocar um espaço dentro dos colchetes:

```
/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=(?:.*?\d){9})[a-z\d ]{12,}$/i
                                    ^ aqui
```

Repare que tem um espaço entre o `\d` e o `]`.

Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), ou seja, pegam qualquer caractere que esteja dentro deles.

No caso, `[a-z\d ]`, significa "uma letra de `a` a `z`, **ou** um `\d` (dígito de 0 a 9), **ou** um espaço".

Comment: Ufa! Vlw. Com a cabeça explodindo já. kkkk

Answer (score 4):

Colocando o `\` ao final dentro do `[]` deve funcionar.

```
var filter = /^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=(?:.*?\d){9})[a-z\d\ ]{12,}$/i;
```

```php
^ # inicio
(?=.*?[a-z]) # procura por caracteres `a` atá `z` pelo menos 1
(?=(?:.*?\d){9}) # procura por 9 digitos 
[a-z\d ]{12,} # tem que ter 12 digitos ou mais entre `a` e `z`  numeros e espaços

$ # fim
```

[Link para testador online](https://regex101.com/r/eSAbir/2)

Comment: Boa! Obrigado. vlw!